# Are prepositions ever a wide open class in any language?

Tags: prepositions, word-classes

I am trying to see if I can come up with new prepositions according to [my thoughts on getting rid of prepositions](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/157bzi9/getting_rid_of_adpositions_in_a_conlang_does_this/) (for a conlang).

First, prepositions are "before things" traditionally, but I think of them as "after" things. Don't know if that is important. But you have prepositions after *verbs*, and after *nouns*.

#### After Verbs

- I worry **about** stuff.
- I listen **to** music.
- I cope **with** my condition.

#### After Nouns

- The age **at** which you are allowed to vote.
- The grass **on** the hill.
- The tree **over by** the rock.

#### Templates/Patterns

It appears as though you first need to convert the "after noun" form into an "after verb" form:

> - The grass, where the grass **is on** the hill.
> - The tree, where the tree **is over by** the rock.

The template/pattern is basically, a preposition *shortens* such a complex expression like those last statements (with the "where" clause) into a discrete word or word sequence.

But you can take it further, where the "after verb" preposition is broken down into a verb + complement:

- on ~ arrive attach

So we have:

```
the grass, where the grass is arrive attach the hill
the grass,̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶t̶t̶a̶c̶h̶ the hill
the grass *on* the hill
```

- on: where the x is arrive attach

So then it seems you can "expand" prepositions into this where clause + verb + complement, and the preposition is just *shorthand* for that sort of long phrase. Just a thought. Somehow I have a feeling that prepositions are a complex and arbitrary shortener for complex phrases, which is perhaps support for why *[Lexical and Functional Prepositions in Acquisition: Evidence for a Hybrid Category](https://www.bu.edu/bucld/files/2011/05/29-LittlefieldBUCLD2004.pdf)* says prepositions aren't as fundamental as nouns/verbs/adjectives, and why they are so awkward.

#### Question

So in thinking about that, I am wondering if languages have "freely open" classes of prepositions. In English I saw here that, at least in past versions of English, prepositions were an open class (though I don't know of examples). But what about old English, or other languages, are there any examples where they are just as open as nouns/verbs/adjectives? Or at least more open than they are in English?

So I try to make up prepositions, working backward from the long "template" sentences above:

> - Start with "where the eating is fixed to the table."
> - Go to "I want to eat, where the eating is fixed arrive the table."
> - Prepositionize: "I want to eat affixed the table."

Something like that perhaps? Where "affix" is a preposition? Or am I doing it wrong?

> - "where the singing is to the sky."
> - "I want to sing, where the singing is to the sky."
> - "I want to sing skyward."

No, that is an adverb. So can there be prepositions after verbs and it *not* be an adverb?

> - "where the crawling is under the ground."
> - "I want to crawl, where the crawling is move below arrive the ground."
> - "I want to crawl mogrunderward."

How about "after noun" prepositions using the template?

> - where the bug is just within the bounds of the garden.
> - the bug, where the bug is just within the bounds of the garden.
> - the bug, where the but is just join enter the bounds base the garden.
> - the bug jentrabase the garden

I don't know, I am trying to create new prepositions, even though it feels clunky (and English doesn't seem to really allow it that much).

Are there languages which allow you to do this sort of thing? Is so, what are a few examples to demonstrate the scope, so I can wrap my head around it better. If not, why not?

Comment: **Pre**-positions are, as the name suggests, not ‘after’ anything. Prepositional phrases (preposition + their complement, traditionally called their object) can appear in lots of different places in sentences and after just about any word class, not just verbs and nouns (what would they be ‘after’ if they’re first in the sentence?). Whether prepositions are somehow a reduction of full sentences is more of a philosophical question than a linguistic one, really – there is certainly no _need_ for such an analysis, and I don’t really think it’s a useful starting point for conlanging.

Comment: I recommend studying some traditional syntax. If you get used to ideas like constituency, recursion, and adjuncts, some of this will make more sense. As Janus says, prepositions don't have to come after anything: "on Tuesday I'm leaving for a week".

Comment: That said, you can certainly make prepositions an open class in your language if you want to. English has a bit of it, with words like _during_ being on the fence between being participles (i.e., verbs/nouns, depending on use) and prepositions. I can’t think of any good examples off the top of my head, but I’m sure there are languages that have specific verbal forms or nominal cases that can be shoehorned into making prepositions more easily than in English and might be considered to have prepositions as an ‘open’ class.

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of prepositions? Whatever you say something means in  your conlang is what it will mean.

Comment: Proto-Indo-European, according to reconstructions, treated prepositions as a special type of gerund. Also we do form new prepositions in English, but mostly as mathematical operations (e.g. addition has the preposition "plus", as in "two plus two is 4": "plus" functions as a preposition).

Answer (score 3):

There is a term "adposition" which avoids the "pre-" vs "post-" problem. I don't know if your issue is specifically with prepositions (and not postpositions), or is it with adpositions in general.

Not everything that you cited is an example of a "preposition", there is also a set of "particles" in "verb-particle" constructions, as in "look up", "tear down", which don't mean the same thing as normal prepositions and don't behave the same as them. Germanic languages happen to have a lot of verbs that are verb-particle pairs.

There is a strong tendency for people to think of adpositions in terms of their semantic function, therefore if you are hunting for adpositions in a language you might look for the equivalent of "under the table", "by the table", "away from the table", focusing on spacial relations, because the English words are prepositions so you might find an adposition in another language that expresses the same concept. If you are focused on a semantically-driven categorization of markers, you would be inclined to take "under the table" to exemplify a likely adposition but not do so with "every", "his" and so on. Yet all of these words come before the noun, so what is it about "under" that makes it seem prepositiony but not "every" or "his"?

One thing is syntax: prepositions come before articles, adjectives etc come after. That might lead you to think that quantifiers and selectors like "all, most, which" are prepositions. You could also appeal to semantic properties to conclude that "under" is a preposition and "all" is not.

Appealing to semantics as an arbiter of prepositionality, we can say that "under" must be a preposition since it has no use other than its adpositional uses, and "stomach" *could* be an adposition, translating "inside" as well as literally referring to a body organ (this is common in African languages), but "fire" or "spider" are not plausible prepositions, since there is no sensible metaphor involving these words: but even if some language did turn "spider" into a spacial term meaning "moving across", this only works when the relationship is conventionalized. Which is contrary to the goal of having an open-ended set of "prepositions". Which is why there is no set of open-ended prepositions, unlike nouns or verbs.

Comment: So could you say "The spider walked aspider the room."? And have aspider mean, walking around like a spider.

Comment: Also, could you provide some examples of cases where there are more clever pronouns outside the ~150 English is said to offer? Or are you saying there aren't any cases of that?

Comment: "back" is a very common one for "behind"; in Kpelle you have "mouth" for "in", "hand" for "from", "ground floor" for "down"; also, in 'serial verb' constructions, verbs like "take", "get", "give", "go" take on a quasi-prepositional function.

Comment: I've yet to find a language where fully there are _no_ prepositions. Though it appears there are only [17 in arabic](https://imanupdate.com/prepositions-in-arabic/)? Any examples taking it to zero? So I would either like to have an open class of prepositions (which it sounds like is never possible), or a completely _gone_ class of prepositions haha. Sorry that's more a conlang question, but this was generally a linguistics question as a whole.

Comment: Japanese has only postpositions, I assume you don't mean specifically **pre**positions.

Comment: Yidiny is a candidate, see the WALS article https://wals.info/chapter/85

Comment: Yeah I mean avoiding or opening the class of adpositions, not just prepositions.

Comment: "The lightning sparked anet the clouds". Where "anet" is like "amongst" but like a network spreading out. A made up preposition?!

Comment: ChatGPT to the rescue, made these: "Glimmerward": The fairies danced glimmerward the enchanted crystal, drawn to its soft glow. "Eldertop": The brave adventurers ascended eldertop the ancient tower, seeking the wisdom of the wizard dwelling there. "Duskgrove": The elven archers patrolled duskgrove the forest, their keen eyes ever watchful as twilight fell. "Mistborne": The ghostly apparitions appeared mistborne the veil of ethereal mist, hovering just above it. "Dreamdeep": The dreamweavers guided the young dreamers dreamdeep the realm of fantasy, where they could explore fantastical realms.